# Solr FieldCollapsing for More Like This queries

Tags: php, solr, grouping, morelikethis, fieldcollapsing

I want to use a "More Like This" query to find similar documents and collapse those that have the same value for the field 'image'. I tried to use the [Field Collapsing parameters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) however they do not seem to work for "More like this".

Below is a snippet of my code. Can you tell me how to collapse results using the "More Like This" query?

```
$url = "http://{$host}:{$port}/solr/{$core}/mlt";

$data = [
    'stream.body' => $content,
    'fl' => 'image,content,title,signature',
    'start' => 0,
    'order' => "score desc",
    'wt' => 'json',
    'mlt.fl' => 'content,title',
    // these lines do nothing ---v
    'group' => 'true',
    'group.field' => 'image',
    'group.sort' => 'impressions desc',
    'group.main' => 'true'
];

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);

$options = array (
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
);

curl_setopt_array($curlHandle , $options);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curlHandle));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General answer

I could not collapse results using Field Collapsing paramaters. However, I was able to achieve the desired result using [CollapsingQParserPlugin](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CollapsingQParserPlugin).
The following filter query collapses documents on the field 'image' and selects the one with the highest value for the field 'impressions': `{!collapse field=image max=impressions}`

## Implementation

For some reason I was not able to combine this filter query with my other filter queries under a single key as follows:

```
$filterQueries = [
    "-signature:{$signature}",
    ...
    "{!collapse field=image max=impressions}"
];
$data = [
    ...
    'fq' => implode(' AND ', $filterQueries),
    ...
];
```

This produced the error: Query does not implement createWeight

My fix was to do a GET request (instead of a POST, which was done in the question above). With the GET request it is possible to have a key for each filter query: http://solr-url/mtl?...&fq=-signature%3A0&...&fq=%7B!collapse+field%3Dimage+max%3Dimpressions%7D

Below is the php solution for the snippet in the question:

```
$url = "http://{$host}:{$port}/solr/{$core}/mlt?"; // Note the added question mark

$data = [
    'stream.body' => $content,
    'fl' => 'image,content,title,signature',
    'fq' => $filterQueries,
    'start' => 0,
    'order' => "score desc",
    'wt' => 'json',
    'mlt.fl' => 'content,title'
];

$params = [];
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $subvalue) {
            $subvalue = urlencode($subvalue);
            $params[] = "{$key}={$subvalue}";
        }
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
        $params[] = "{$key}={$value}";
    }
}
$url .= implode('&', $params);

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);
$options = array ();
curl_setopt_array($curlHandle , $options);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curlHandle));
```