# solr more like this get grouped result

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I have more like this query in `solr` and I would like to group result based on special field. I used group feature in `solr`.

I set:

```
group = true & group.field = field 1 & group.limit = 3
```

And I have this [query](http://localhost:8983/solr/post/mlt?q=id%3A987&fl=id%2Ccollection_id%2Cscore&wt=json&indent=true&mlt.boost=true&mlt.qf=collection_topic%5E110%20title%5E130&mlt.fl=collection_topic%20title%20&group=true&group.field=collection_id&group.limit=3)

But as I see more like this does not support group. I use solr 5.3.1

**Questions**

- How I can group `solr` result?
- Why `solr` does not support group?

Comment: Are you looking for [Result Clustering](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Clustering)? Otherwise - See [FieldCollapsing for More Like This queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563507/solr-fieldcollapsing-for-more-like-this-queries).

Comment: fieldCollapsing return just maxScore doc in each group. but i need get for example 3 doc  in each group

Answer (score -1):

Use the CollapsingQParser as documented here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results

For instance, if you want to group for `field1` and `limit 3` as you mentioned:

```
fq={!collapse field=fiedl1 max=3}
```

Comment: max=3 is not limiting the results per cluster, it is to returns "the group head document for each group based on which document has the min or max value of the specified numeric field or function query." as per the document.